# Is JavaScript closure rules for IE different with event handler?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scope, closures, event-listener

My script works perfectly with FF and Chrome, but not with an IE. Here's a simple isomorph:

```js
(function() {
 var closure = "hi";

 var f = function() {
  console.dir(closure);
 };

 f(); // hi

 window.onload = function() {
  f(); // undefined
 };
}());
```

Is my code wrong and GC/FF just being lenient? If I want to design a similar functionality, how can I achieve this on multiple platforms?

Comment: `console.dir` is only available in IE 9+. Maybe that's the issue? Everything else here is supported.

Comment: @4castle - the comments imply that the output is `hi` and `undefined` ... if the OP were using IE8- neither console.dir would work :p

Comment: if you stoke up the coals and fire up internet exploder and click on Run code snippet, just before you lose all self esteem for actually using internet exploder, you'll see `hi` logged twice in the console, as it does with all relevant browsers that are current - so, at least the "simple isomorph" in the question does not demonstrate the issue as reported by the OP. And the suggestion that  IE is right and real browsers are wrong in the statement `GC/FF just being lenient?` made me laugh ... no, GC/FF are never wrong if they both do things one way and IE does it another

Comment: `console.dir` has no problem. I should've put my question more straightforward... That `f()` inside `window.onload`, that works fine in GC/FF (prints hi) and not in IE11 (prints undefined). I know that GC/FF are usually much more loyal to the standards, just thought maybe it's kinda customary non-standard feature that IE has overlooked or something.

Comment: In short, how do I use the variable closure inside window.onload, not only in GCFF but also in IE? Doesn't have to support older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem. I create a sample using the following code, it seems that everything works well on my side (Chrome and IE 11(11.1.17134.0)), please refer to it.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var closure = "hi";
            var f = function (message) {
                console.dir(message);
            };
            f(closure); // hi
            window.onload = function () {
                f("world"); //
            };
        }());
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

The result as below:
[image]